# て form with -たい is wrong right?

Tags: て-form

On a youtube channel I found such an example: "**暑くてお酒を飲みたい**"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkFPCNt9ZKo&t=864s

Isn't this wrong?

I mean て form  as reason can be used for feelings or for what you can't do, as explained [here](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html).

But you shouldn't use it for what you want to do  (-tai form)

Am I wrong?

Comment: This lesson is very confusing in my opinion, て form is a very flexible form and one of the most common use is simply to link sentences. But it never says you can't use it with たい, what is your confusion?

Comment: @Simon, て-form is very flexible, but it still has restrictions. Mostly related to volition. It's not very important when we have 2 actions done by the subject, because we do actions with some aim/reason. But once we change that, we have to provide a cause/reason. Some of sentences become less natural, for example, "I woke up and brushed my teeth". Do a test "why you brushed your teeth? Because I woke up". Kinda weird, right? But I'm not sure about ーたい, because it can express both emotions (uncontrollable) and volition (plan to do it). It sounds ok, but I would like a native's confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `暑くてお酒を飲みたい` sounds a bit unnatural, but the following is fairly usual:

- 暑くてお酒を飲みたいと思ったけど、冷蔵庫を見たら何もなかった
- It was hot and I wanted to drink alcohol, but there was nothing when I checked the fridge.

Some examples with ...て...たい without being followed by additional phrases:

- 暑すぎて裸になりたい It is too hot and I want to go totally naked.
- 恥ずかしくて穴があったら入りたい I'm so ashamed, and want to hide in a pit if there is any.
- 失恋して死にたい I got my heart broken and want to die.

After thinking and a bit googling about ...て...たい, it is true that such sentences tend to become unnatural, but it can be ok especially when the intended meaning is *it is too ... that I want to ...*.

Comment: The first example is not technically an example of …て…たい, because it's 暑くて + (お酒を飲みたいと)思った.